# Android simulation of activityRecognition events

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, activity-recognition

Is there a way to simulate / generate activity recognition events (i.e. - walking) in junits for a android application?  My goal is to fully test the logic I have that is related to receiving an activity recognition event and not the activity recognition process.

Any pointers apprciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially got around the issue by refactoring such that my detected activity is processed in it's own AsyncTask class.  I then wrote a series of junits that could pass in a simulate event information to this activity detection processing class.  Given  that android has a limit on the number of asynctask executes that can be executed per object, my junit creates runnables in a loop to interact with the activity processing class.

I also found the otto and dagger2 libraries that may work to inject events into the android bus.  Still a work in progress though...